# Varnish: Exclude section of page

Tags: performance, reverse-proxy, cache, varnish, performance-tuning

Is there any way to exclude some webpage parts from cache? For example, I have Recent Additions block on my homepage which gets refreshed after every 15mins.

I know there is something like [ESI Features](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/ESIfeatures) but don' know if I am going in right direction. If it yes is there any example how to implement it?

I found following three articles regarding ESI

1. [Edge Side Includes integration](http://drupal.org/project/esi)
2. [Controlling Varnish ESI inside your application](http://www.raspberry.nl/2010/07/05/controlling-varnish-esi-inside-your-application/)
3. [Edge Side Includes with Varnish in 10 minutes](http://css.dzone.com/articles/edge-side-includes-varnish-10)

Answer (score 1):

ESI is definitely the way to go. You basically need to break your webpage into individual sections, and include them with ESI commands in HTML. Varnish then processes the ESI, and pulls all of the sections together.

The only other way to do it, would be to use Ajax calls to populate the changing bits, and override the cache times for those specific calls.

Varnish itself has some good documentation on this:
https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/esi.html